# Show result in the MessageBox

Tags: c#, string

There is a code for the 3 most frequently occurring word

```
string words = "One one Two two three four".ToLower();

var results = words
  .Split(' ')
  .Where(x => x.Length > 3)
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .Select(x => new { 
     Count = x.Count(), 
     Word = x.Key })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
  .Take(3);

foreach (var item in results)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} occurred {1} times", item.Word, item.Count));
}
```

It works but I want to press button once  and show all result in the MessageBox like this:

[image]

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious? Concatenate the string in a loop and only show the message box once?

Answer (score 1):

Join the strings then only show the message box once:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\n", results.Select(x => String.Format("{0} occurred {1} times", x.Word, x.Count)));
```

or using string interpolation:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\n", 
                   results.Select(x => $"{x.Word} occurred {x.Count} times"));
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to build your string you want to show in the message box in the foreach loop and then call the MessageBox.Show method.
To get linebreaks you can use "\n" or Environment.NewLine.
To build the string you can use the stringbuilder.

For example:

```
var stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in results)
{
    stringBuilder.Append($"{item.Word} occurred {item.Count} times");
    stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

If you make a list out of the results `.ToList()` you can write the foreach even shorter:

```
var stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

results.ForEach(r => stringBuilder.Append($"{r.Word} occurred {r.Count} times{Environment.NewLine}"));

MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());
```